# How to Set Border thickness of Apache POI XWPFTable table?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I need to set my table that would like to look BOLD so how to set thickness border?

I know how to change borders
   `borders.addNewBottom().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);`

But how to change border thickness?

EDIT: 
I've done it.
Like this:

```
table3.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getTop().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(11));
                        table3.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getLeft().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(12));
                        table3.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getRight().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(12));
                        table3.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getBottom().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(12));
                        table3.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideH().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(12));
                        table3.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideV().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(12));
```

BTW where the hell am I supposed to know what it means by setSz?

Comment: "where the hell i supposed to know what means setSz?": [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), which is the file format of `*.docx` files, is open standard defined in [ECMA-376: Page 293/294](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference%20(tagged).pdf#page=299&zoom=130,80,250).

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
borders.addNewBottom().setVal(STBorder.THICK);
```

The STBorder class contains both line borders and art borders. Everything down to inset is a line border, and can be used wherever borders can be used. Everything from apple on down is an art border and can only be used for page borders.